# Internship concerns

Tags: graduate-school

I started my internship in the summer of 2018 and was unable to complete all the hours during the semester, I received an incomplete for a grade until I could finish my hours in the Spring of 2019.  Now, I have completed all related course work.  my question is that I have the dean of my program supervising me for the remainder of my hours and it is one hour a week on video chat.  she wants to record the video chats (which I feel uncomfortable with) and now wants to give me a new syllabus for working with her and to complete additional work.  I feel if she is giving me an additional syllabus that is actually considered another class.  Suggestions on how to handle this

Comment: What's the problem, the fact that your dean is recording the conversation or that you are tasked with a whole new class to complete the missing hours?

Comment: If you feel uncomfortable about the recording, then let the dean know. If you wanted to know if this is legal, try https://law.stackexchange.com/. As for the "an additional syllabus" have you asked the dean why this would be a whole new 'class' instead of completing the previous 'class'?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right to ask what she will do with the video chats. She also might have the right to tell you that she is recording them without your consent. Sort of a "too bad, so sad, I'm the boss." type of thing. The actual legal details will depend a great deal on where you are. In my state in the U.S., if I am engaging in a voluntary meeting, the other party can audio record me (for non-commercial purposes) without my consent. (The laws are different for an dissociated 3rd party). You may not have a large *legal* leg to stand on. In most universities in the U.S., you can be recorded *without your consent or knowledge* if you are engaging in a classroom activity and the professor has initiated the recording. States with one-party or mixed consent laws on recordings almost always will allow universities to record anything considered "classroom activity" if the professor (or even an engaged student) is aware that the recording is taking place.

As for the new syllabus, perhaps she is just trying to formalize what she expects from you. If she wants you to complete additional work, then you can of course address your concerns with her. This is especially true if you have a syllabus for the previous agreements for the internship and the new syllabus does not agree with the old one.

ADDENDUM: Perhaps this is just my cynicism speaking, but we do need to state the fact that the (professor/university admin) to (student) relationship is often very one-sided in terms of power. Short of committing a legal infraction, most professors will be allowed to get away with about whatever they want. They can give you extra homework. They can make you jump through hoops to get a good grade. They can even make you take unfair and extremely difficult tests. School is not "fair."

Comment: even though I have a incomplete in the class, the original professor is not teaching this semester so I have another professor which is the dean completing my supervision, who is asking for me to complete additional work for her

Comment: @user103763 You may then want to consider if it would be more work to fight against the dean or just do the extra work she wants. If the previous professor gave you a syllabus, it would seem that you could just show that to the dean and tell her what work the previous professor expected. At my former university, in order to give a student an "incomplete," I (as the professor) had to write down in detail exactly what would be expected of the student going forward. The form explicitly stated that no more, and no less, work was to then be expected of the student.

Comment: *She also has the right to tell you that she is recording them.* I'm not sure what you mean by this. Yes, she obviously has the right to tell you just about anything. Do you mean she is obliged to? Or that she has the right to record you without your consent as part of this job-related activity?

Comment: @AzorAhai As in "she can tell you what to do because she is in charge." It is a matter of "I'm telling you, not asking you." She also has the right to sit there and tell you nothing about her recording. I am using the word "tell" not to mean "to inform for one's interest," but rather as "to inform another from a position of authority."

Comment: @Vladhagen She doesn't have the "right to sit there and tell you nothing" in my state. Maybe you could mention your jurisdiction or move the YMMV statement before that comment.

Comment: @AzorAhai That thought is addressed in my answer. I am not getting into the detailed semantic battles. And understand that wiretap laws in the educational setting are not as clear cut as people think. Believe me, I have worked in education law and policy. Even in two-party consent states, consent can be *implicit*. It can also be embedded in user agreements of educational software. If you agreed to use the learning management system, sometimes you have agreed to be recorded without your explicit knowing in every instance. This can be true *even in two party consent states.*

Comment: @AzorAhai See 18 U.S.C. 2511(2)(d). for the federal (U.S.) statute. Although state laws sometimes (attempt) to trump the federal law, state laws do not always hold jurisdictional preference in all situations. It depends on who is being recorded and where. There's a reason that entire legal journals are devoted to privacy laws. It would be a naive and misguided understanding of the law to believe that two-party consent states provide absolute protection in these cases. See for example the *Melongo* and *Clark* (*State v.*) decisions in Illinois.

Comment: @Vladhagen Thanks for the info. I still think your leading sentences are a bit confusing to read

Comment: What LMS are you referring to, though?

Comment: @AzorAhai I once worked at a school that had an in house LMS. Part of the user agreement was "Any interactions with this site may be recorded for training and educational purposes."

Comment: @Vladhagen No, I mean, I don't think the OP mentioned using an LMS anywhere. I've also never heard of an LMS offering video conferencing, did yours?

Comment: @AzorAhai I referred to an LMS as one example of educational interaction that has more complicated legal aspects in terms of wire tap laws. You seemed adamant that no one would ever have the right to record you in your state without your "consent." I was providing one example of where the interaction is more complicated and where consent is sometimes implicit. I am aware of LMS services that have video conferencing embedded.

Comment: @Vladhagen Well, you said "the learning management system," which confused me because I wasn't sure which one you were referring to.

Comment: @AzorAhai "I am not getting into the detailed semantic battles."

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I'm just trying to understand your post. Have a good one.